# How can I render these edges more realistic?

Tags: modeling

I would like to have a realistic rendering with this hard surface. These edges appear too soft to look realistic, so I applied a 'Mark Sharp' but they appear with the same rendering as if I didn't apply any Mark Sharp. What am I doing wrong?
[image]
[image]

I tried many things. On the middle crease of 0.44 and on the right, a bevel with two edges. Is there a better way or if not what is the more realistic option?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Both threads complement each other. Should i delete one? Which one? – Grobby 12 mins ago

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the edge sharpness by increasing the '**Mean Crease**' 
[image]